# Pass and get object with ASMX WebService

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2005

We have a web service like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public object[] DoSmt(object[] inParams)
{
    List<object> rsl = new List<object>();
    rsl.Add(DateTime.Now);
    rsl.Add(new CallResult());
    return rsl.ToArray();
}
```

`CallResult` class is defined in web service. We call this method from WinForms (before that we add a web reference to this web service):

```
Service svc = new Service();
object[] arrRsl = svc.DoSmt(new object[] { "hi there", "hello" });
```

We get an exception says

> App do not know how to deserialize CallResult

But if we put a funny function like this into the web service:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void Fun(CallResult abc)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

then everything is ok. It is because `CallResult` does not appear in WSDL file before adding of funny function because it does not appear in any `WebMethod`.

The question is: **How to inform C# to generate `CallResult` in WSDL file even if it does not explicitly be used in any `WebMethod`. We use VS2005.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the class with the [GenerateScriptTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.generatescripttypeattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

> In some cases, even if the type corresponds to an input parameter or
>   return value of a Web service method, the proxy will not be generated
>   automatically. In that case, you must use the
>   GenerateScriptTypeAttribute attribute to generate the proxy object for
>   the type.

```
[GenerateScriptType(typeof(ColorObject), ScriptTypeId = "Color")]
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetDefaultColor()
{
    // Instantiate the default color object.
    ColorObject co = new ColorObject();

    return co.rgb;
}
```

Comment: In .Net 2.0 just add [XmlInclude(typeof(CallResult))]